# MS SQL Поиск и удаление записей по DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, запрос, request

Есть простая таблица:

```
create table Files
(
  Id          int identity,
  Content     varbinary(max),
  CteatedAt   datetime default getdate()
)
```

Мне необходимо составить запрос, который будет удалять с таблицы все записи, в которых поле `Content = null` и от даты создания файла `CteatedAt` прошло более 2-х часов.

Написать запрос на удаление данных где поле `Content` пустое труда не составило:

```
DELETE
FROM Files
WHERE Content IS NULL
```

А вот как находить записи у которых с момента даты создания прошло более 2-х часов я не знаю. Подскажите как такое делается, буду благодарен.

Должно быть что-то вроде этого, только как правильно это сделать я не понимаю:

```
DELETE
FROM Files
WHERE Content IS NULL
AND (GETDATE() - CteatedAt) > 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM Files
WHERE Content IS NULL
AND CteatedAt < DATEADD(hh, -2, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать как такое делается)