# Запрос Year Getdate - 2 года

Tags: sql, sql-server

Просьба подсказать, есть запрос

DELETE FROM testdb
WHERE LASTDATE < 2018

LASTDATE имеет тип данных datetime

но нужен универсальный джоб, который удаляет все что ниже -2 года от текущего года
DELETE FROM testdb
WHERE LASTDATE < SELECT YEAR (GETDATE()) - 2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MS SQL Поиск и удаление записей по DATETIME](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950139/ms-sql-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-datetime)

Comment: там остается формат datetime
то есть месяц дни минуты ... мне нужно отсечь эти условия и удалять только по году

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию year ()

```
DELETE FROM testdb WHERE year(LASTDATE) <2018

or

DELETE FROM testdb WHERE year(LASTDATE) <  YEAR (GETDATE ()) - 2
```

Comment: тьфу ты ... это действительно было просто, благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Гм, совет использовать функцию `year(LASTDATE)` - не совсем хорош. Есть понятие *sargability* - про возможность использовать индексы при условиях запроса. Функция `year(LASTDATE)` таковой не является, что будет приводить к сканированию таблицы, даже если есть индекс по полю `LASTDATE`.

Пример кода, который возвращает дату начала текущего года - 2.

```
DECLARE @t AS DATETIME;
SET @t = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(0 AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) - 2, CAST(0 AS DATETIME));
DELETE FROM testdb WHERE LASTDATE < @t;
```

И этот запрос - *sargable*, то есть может использовать индекс по полю `LASTDATE`.